# dagger 2 'can not be provided without'

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

To simplify problem prerequisites suppose the following sources set:

src/**main**/java/di

ApplicationComponent.java:

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(MyApplication target);
}
```

ApplicationModule.java

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides @PerApplication
    CoffeeMaker provideCoffeeMaker(CoffeeMakerImpl impl) { return impl; }
}
```

src/**debug**/java/di

DebugApplicationComponent.java:

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = {DebugApplicationModule.class})
public interface DebugApplicationComponent extends ApplicationComponent {}
```

DebugApplicationModule.java

```
@Module(includes = ApplicationModule.class)
public class DebugApplicationModule {
    @Provides @PerApplication
    Heater provideHeater(HeaterImpl impl) { return impl; }
}
```

src/**main**/java/app

CoffeeMakerImpl.java

```
class CoffeeMakerImpl implements CoffeeMaker {
    @Inject CoffeeMakerImpl(Heater heater) {}
}
```

In MyApplication.java

```
@Inject CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker;

DaggerDebugApplicationComponent.
    builder().
    applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(application)).
    debugApplicationModule(new DebugApplicationModule()).
    build().
    inject(this);
```

When compiling the project I got error:

```
Error:(18, 10) error: Heater cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
app.Heater is injected at
app.CofeeMakerImpl.<init>(heater)
app.CofeeMakerImpl is injected at
app.MyApplication
app.MyApplication is injected at
di.ApplicationComponent.inject(target)
```

I expect, that due `DebugApplicationModule` **includes** `ApplicationModule`, and I pass to `DebugApplicationComponent` both of these modules, `DebugApplicationComponent`, should see both `Heater` and `CoffeeMaker`.

What could be a reason, why `Heater` is not accessible in injection chain?

**P.S.** Thanks to @DavidMedenjak, solution is quite simple: just make ApplicationComponent a plain interface, removing `@PerApplication @Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})` line.

*See his answer, there are some useful advices there.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect, that due `DebugApplicationModule` **includes** `ApplicationModule` [...] should see both `Heater` and `CoffeeMaker`.

`DebugApplicationModule` compiles fine, the problem is that your **`ApplicationComponent`** cannot compile, since it does not know how to inject `MyApplication`.

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
  void inject(MyApplication target);
}
```

Here you declare that this component knows how to inject `MyApplication`, but it has no access or knowledge about `Heater`, as you can see in the compile error:

```
error:(18, 10) error: Heater cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
app.Heater is injected at
app.CofeeMakerImpl.<init>(heater)
app.CofeeMakerImpl is injected at
app.MyApplication
app.MyApplication is injected at  <- trying to inject MyApplication
di.ApplicationComponent.inject(target) <- ApplicationComponent has the problem
```

Make sure to always look very closely at the compile errors. 
You only add this knowledget to your `DebugApplicationModule`, but `ApplicationComponent` also says it can inject the class, which it can't.

---

To solve this the obvious solutions would be to remove the `inject()` signature from your `ApplicationComponent` and move it to your `DebugApplicationComponent`, since it just doesn't know how to inject it. The full information to inject your `Application` is within your `DebugApplicationComponent`, and later maybe also `ReleaseApplicationComponent`.

Since you probably want an interface that your components implement, you could also just remove the `@Component` annotation from `ApplicationComponent`.

```
public interface ApplicationComponent {
  void inject(MyApplication target);
}
```

Make it a plain interface, and Dagger will not try to generate an implementation.

You could also have a look at component builder methods, where you could bind / add different objects / modules to a component.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot! I have removed @Component from ApplicationComponent and no problem. inject()'s must reside in ApplicationComponent, because also there is a ReleaseApplicationComponent, having the same injects targets as DebugApplicationComponent.